# Chrome not opening when started inside jar

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jar, selenium-chromedriver

Following is the main Code:

```
private WebDriver driver = null;
try
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
                 "C:\\Jars\\chromedriver.exe");
       driver = new ChromeDriver();
   System.out.println("after chrome");
}
catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When the above code is executed as stand alone java, the driver was initialized and I was able to use for automation.

But when above code is packaged into a jar file, 
print statement after driver = new ChromeDriver(); is not called.

Note: chromedriver.exe is **outside** the jar file

Could anyone help me understand this problem

Comment: Reading the stack trace might help.

Comment: Are there any errors? Can you add println before the line to make sure your code is even called or not?

Comment: @JB Nizet and Tarun Lalwani : there was no error / exception. Println before the statement worked fine. Since there was no error/ exception, i couldnt guess the problem

Answer (score 0):

Too silly of me!. I missed http client jar files while building. This created the problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are fogot to upload jars.. Add them